# Select Workbook Excel already Open with a Button Click Method

Tags: c#, vsto, excel

I have a problem, I want insert data with a button click method, but this method are created in a Ribbon menu (VSTO).

To understand better this, I want make a query on a database send it to a list of persons, and print on excel what i want see from that persons. For example, i just want see name and birthdate, or name, id and profession.

To do this i need select the Workbook opened when i run the application. So i try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisWorkbook.InnerObject;
            Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            ws.Cells[1, 2] = "teste";
        }
```

- using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
- using ExcelTools = Microsoft.Office.Tools;
- using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

But i get this error: 
`**"Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B74CBB86-9C9F-4172-9AE7-3CE4A7BFA5EB}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."**`

Probably is more easy than i'm seeing, but i'm so tired, and i need finish this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

man try this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime;
Excel.Worksheet wsheet =
  (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

Answer (score 3):

The following should work (remove the .InnerObject)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
        { 
            Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisWorkbook; 
            Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets["Sheet1"]; 
            ws.Cells[1, 2] = "teste"; 
        }
```

The [InnerObject property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.innerobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns a reference to the underlying (read COM) workbook. The return type is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook (and not Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook which is the .Net wrapped version of a workbook)

The same applies to sheets as well:
If you access the Sheets collection of the native Com workbook it will return a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkSheet and accessing the Excel.Workbook will return a Excel.WorkSheet

For more about vsto wrapped object see: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668196%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)